# How to store user information in token in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have to store token in cache that comes from rest api for about 1 hour of time. I am new to this so don't know much about same, Please help me to guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use jwt token or cache helper for same.

Comment: thnx uc57, i try them.